# Extract value from JSON using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, loops, iterator

I got the following response from the server using Java

```
{"success":true,"errors":[],"requestId":"blah blah","warnings":[],"result":[{"id":1023,"name":"Email","description":"", subject":{"type":"Text","value":"Some value"}}]
```

I want to access the id and subject's -> value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This questions was already answered, type this to the Search field: `parse json [java]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

[**JacksonXML**](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

To parse this JSON response to Java object, and next validate it, in your custom conditions.

There are also similar libraries like `gson` from Google or `Xpath`. I recommend Jackson because Spring framework use this and it's very easy to use in production grade.